# Printing one dimensional array in C

Tags: c, arrays, printing

In Python I can define a list, and print it all with one command:

```
lst = [1,2,3]
print lst
[1,2,3]
```

Is there any equivalent command in C ? (without using loops), or do I have to print every element by himself?

Thanks!

Comment: Wellcome to SO. Why would someone want to do this? Is this homework? What have you tried? Please have a tour through the help like on top to know what questions we expect here.

Comment: No, there is no such a way. Even if you find a function claiming to do that, it will use an internal loop.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Nonsense. Ever heard of recursion? See my answer.

Comment: @FUZxxl Don't you consider recursion to be a loop? It is a loop with a space complexity overhead in addition to the same time complexity as regular loop.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Define “loop.”

Comment: It is [defined already](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/loop)

Comment: @EugeneSh. In this case, my answer uses a loop. I would use a more restrictive definition of the term “loop” though.

Comment: I guess it depends on the OPs definition. Perhaps your answer is what he needs..

Comment: @ EugeneSh Thanks, that's the answer I've been looking for. In python I can define a list, for example 'lst = [1,2,3]' and when I command 'print lst' the program will print [1,2,3]. I just wanted to know if it is possible on C.

Answer (score 3):

You can use recursion like in this pseudo code:

```
void print_array(item array[], size_t len)
{
    if (len == 0)
        return;

    print_item(*array);
    print_array(array + 1, len - 1);
}
```

Modern C compilers can optimize away tail-recursion, so this is likely not much less efficient than a loop.

Comment: @pmg How embarrassing. And I'm trying to get a golden [c] badge...

Comment: Now it's good. I +1 anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

If it's a string then yes, you can dump the entire contents of the array as long as it's \0 (nul) terminated...fprintf and the likes dump entire arrays all of the time.

```
char *p;
char string[12] = "A string";

for (p = &string[0]; *p != '\0'; p++)
    fprintf(stdout, "%c", *p);
```

Is akin to

```
printf("%s", string);
```